# Dynamically loading resource dictionary files to a wpf application gives an error

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I am trying to add a xaml resource file dynamically using the statement,

```
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri("resources/leaf_styles.xaml", UriKind.Relative) });
```

This is throwing an exception, **Cannot locate resource 'resources/leaf_styles.xaml'.**

I added the leaf_styles.xaml file to the project under resource folder and the BuildAction is set to "Content", CopyAlways is set to True. Still I get this error. Could some one help me out pointing whats wrong??

Additional information -

- **I don't want to embed the xaml file as a resource**
- **The current project is a .net 3.5 class library project**
- **The above mergedictionary statement is written in a class belonging to the same project**
- **I also added the [assembly: AssemblyAssociatedContentFile("resources/leaf_styles.xaml")] manually once I figured that this is not working (for testing)**

### Update

If I give it as an absolute location, it is working properly.

```
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri(@"D:\foo\trunk\bin\resources\leaf_styles.xaml", UriKind.Absolute) });
```

Comment: Does it work if you give it an absolute path (just for testing)?

Comment: Yeah, if I give it as an absolute path, it is working. 

Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri(@"D:\foo\trunk\bin\resources\leaf_styles.xaml", UriKind.Absolute) });

Answer (score 29, accepted):

At last, it worked. Here is what I did,

1. Went thru' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx.
2. Changed the Uri pattern to

   ```
   var foo = new Uri("pack://siteoforigin:,,,/resources/leaf_styles.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
   Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary() { Source = foo });
   ```

Answer (score 10):

To load a content file, you can call the [GetContentStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.getcontentstream.aspx) method of the Application class, passing a pack URI that identifies the desired content file.

Checkout

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970494.aspx#Content_Files

**EDIT**

I did it successfully like this

```
    Uri uri = new Uri("Resources/MyDict.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
    StreamResourceInfo info = Application.GetContentStream(uri);
    System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader reader = new System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader();
    ResourceDictionary myResourceDictionary = 
                                   (ResourceDictionary)reader.LoadAsync(info.Stream);
    Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(myResourceDictionary);
```

Comment: I don't want to pack my resource file with an assembly. I want to load it as a content file

Comment: the GetContentStream is returning me "null". I guess it has got to do with the project type (!?!)

Comment: I guess it has something to do with the Uri.Check if you have set the build action to content and copy to output directory to always copy

Comment: "The current project is a .net 3.5 class library project", can this create any confusions !?!

Comment: No i have tried it in a 3.5 class library project and its working.This is what i have done.I created a class library project,Added a user control and write the above code in the constructor of the usercontrol.I add reference of system.xaml.If you can reproduce the problem in a test project,upload it somewhere and post the link.I will check the same

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same "missing resource problem" and scratched my head for hours. Then I realized that my assembly name contains dots (.) and changed the resource assembly name, tested again and it worked. It was a 16x16 png image file which ı wanted to load. But I see that dotted assembly names causes error for soma cases and does not cause error for other cases.

- 1) If you are loading a style from resource, it works
- 2) If you are loading an image, it does not work. The resource can not be found.

I used the same code for both cases but results are different. I don't know if it is a wpf bug.