# WPF style from HDD file

Tags: c#, wpf, styles

In my application I'm using ResourceDictionaries for styles. Example:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="SimpleButton">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource SpecialRed}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="40"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Lets say that as a user I know how resource dictionary look like. Is it possible to overwrite the resource from my own file from HDD? I want to add the functionality which allows user to do this.

My HDD file:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="SimpleButton">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource SpecialRed}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="70"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20"/>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Do you mean a developer "user" thats using your control? Or a end user that you want to allow to change the look and feel of your compiled app?

Comment: You want a random end user to mess with your XAML? Yikes. Mine field. Why not just have a settings dialog that's more user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on doing that (I wouldn't), you can merge resource dictionaries at runtime: [Dynamically loading resource dictionary files to a wpf application gives an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030580/dynamically-loading-resource-dictionary-files-to-a-wpf-application-gives-an-erro)