# Load resource dictionary only if file exists

Tags: c#, wpf

is there a way to load Resource Dictionary only if resource file exists?
In the case below, I wish to only allow resource dictionary when the file 'Resources/AdditionalStyles.xaml' exists

```
<ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/AdditionalStyles.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Comment: It is possible to dynamically load the `ResourceDictionary` if it exists from code. You could adapt this tutorial to check if the file exists and then load it if so: https://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/load-resource-dictionaries-at-runtime-in-wpf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could override the `OnStartup` method in your `App.xaml.cs` and then check for the presence of the file, loading it if it does exist:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    var fileName = Environment.CurrentDirectory() + @"\Resources\AdditionalStyles.xaml";

    // Check if the AdditionalStyles.xaml file exists
    if (File.Exists(fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            // try and load the file as a dictionary and add it the dictionaries
            var additionalStylesDict = (ResourceDictionary)XamlReader.Load(fs);
            Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(additionalStylesDict);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // something went wrong loading the resource file
        }
    }

    // any other stuff on startup

    // call the base method
    base.OnStartup(e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try by Dynamically loading it through Code instead of inserting the reference in App.xaml like somebody tried to do in: [Dynamically loading resource dictionary files to a wpf application gives an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030580/dynamically-loading-resource-dictionary-files-to-a-wpf-application-gives-an-erro)

If I'm not mistaken, it should give an exception if said resource does not exist, you could catch that error, or check if the file exists in Path XYZ and do the other logic you want to proceed with:

```
var foo = new Uri("pack://siteoforigin:,,,/resources/leaf_styles.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary() { Source = foo });
```

Answer (score 1):

Load it dynamically:

```
   private void LoadDynamicResource(String sStyle)
    {
        FileInfo fi1 = new FileInfo(sStyle);
        if(fi1.Exists)
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(sStyle, FileMode.Open))
            {
               ResourceDictionary dic = (ResourceDictionary)XamlReader.Load(fs);
               Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
               Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dic);
            }
        }
    }
```