# WPF Form loses it style after showing from another project

Tags: c#, wpf, forms

I have a C# application which contains 2 project, and when I set the first project which contains a [Styled WPF Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAwuw.png) as startup project, it has it's own style and everything is fine. But when I use this code to show that WPF from from a Windows Form Application, the first project's form [loses its own style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bRwH.png):

```
Window introForm;
introForm = new Client.MainWindow();
introForm.Show();
```

I have no idea why it happens

Comment: I suspect there are styles defined in App.xaml for one of your projects but not the other.  You might need to include them from the other project by using a MergedDictionary.

Comment: @RogerN You're right there it loads only the Window not the App.xaml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6042515/7147513

this fixed my problem:

```
var foo = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MyProject;component/Resources/Styles.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary() { Source = foo });
```