# Load UserControl (Property) from Plugin using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

I'm a complete noob to MVVM. Until now, I managed to bind properties from my loaded plugins (which are in a collection) to my textboxes as well as the available plugins to some comboboxes.

Now, I'm struggling with displaying their UI in the host application.

Everywhere, I read something about DataTemplate or MEF, but I really have no idea how to do that. Looks good on paper, but I have no idea how to implement it.

I load my plugins using Reflection.

Is it possible like that?

Everything I need to load is stored in Connections:

Connection.cs

```
public class Connection
{
    public string ConnectionName { get; set; }
    public Plugin<IPlugin> ERP { get; set; }
    public Plugin<IPlugin> Shop { get; set; }

    public Connection(string connName)
    {
        ConnectionName = connName;
    }
}
```

Plugin.cs

```
public class Plugin<T>
{
    public Assembly PluginAssembly { get; set; }
    public Type[] TypeList { get; set; }

    public T PluginInstance { get; set; }

    public Type PluginType { get; set; }

    public Plugin()
    {

    }
}
```

IPlugin.cs

```
public interface IPlugin
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Contains information about the plugin, like version, author and type
    /// </summary>
    PluginInfo Info { get; }
    /// <summary>
    /// List of field lists for different mappings
    /// </summary>
    List<Fieldlist> Fieldlist { get; set; }

    UserControl UI { get; }

    Config Config { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets called at the start of the plugin
    /// </summary>
    void Load();
    /// <summary>
    /// Import function for transferring data into the plugin
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="json">The data to be transferred</param>
    /// <param name="type">The type of data e.g articles, orders, etc.</param>
    void Import(string json, string type);
    /// <summary>
    /// Export function for transferring data out of the plugin
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type">The type of data e.g articles, orders, etc.</param>
    /// <returns>The JSON to be transferred</returns>
    string Export(string type);
}
```

And the "affected" part my MainWindow.xaml:

```
<TabItem Header="ERP">
    <ContentControl Name="ccERP" Background="#FFE5E5E5" Content="{Binding ElementName=lbVerbindungen, Path=SelectedItem.ERP.PluginInstance.UI}"/>
</TabItem>
<TabItem Header="Shop">
    <ContentControl Name="ccShop" Background="#FFE5E5E5" Content="{Binding ElementName=lbVerbindungen, Path=SelectedItem.Shop.PluginInstance.UI}"/>
</TabItem>
```

**EDIT**: My application loads the mentioned plugins at runtime using assemblies as plugins, which need to have an UI of some sort. Setting the content of the ContentControl in the code works fine using `ccERP.Content = ((Connection)lbVerbindungen.SelectedItem).ERP.PluginInstance.UI;`, but it doesn't using the binding I used above.

**EDIT2**: My listbox is done like this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbVerbindungen" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,43" Width="208" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Connections}" DisplayMemberPath="ConnectionName">
                    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <EventSetter Event="Loaded" Handler="ListBoxItem_Loaded"/>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True" >
                                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                            <Style.Resources>
                                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black"/>
                                <!-- Background of selected item when focussed -->
                                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="LightCyan"/>
                                <!-- Background of selected item when not focussed -->
                                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="LightGray" />
                            </Style.Resources>
                        </Style>
                    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                </ListBox>
```

Comment: Sorry for assuming, that this community is here to help people, if they can't find a solution somewhere else. I already looked at tutorials and stuff but literally all of them feature UserControls that are inside the main program. And I understand it like that. However my application loads the UI from plugins and therefor, can't be mapped to static resources, set contexts or anything plus I have 2 of those things. The plugin determines the UI and inside the Connection, I store the used plugin. I can set the content of the ContentControl using GLUE programming but that's not what I want...

Answer (score 0):

The Plugin interface/class shouldn't have a property that returns a `UserControl`. Instead you should define a `DataTemplate` in the view that defines the appearance of a plugin, e.g.:

```
<ContentControl Name="ccERP" Background="#FFE5E5E5" 
                        Content="{Binding ElementName=lbVerbindungen, Path=SelectedItem.ERP.PluginInstance}">
    <ContentControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:IPlugin}">
            <local:PluginUserControl />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Resources>
</ContentControl>
```

An implicit `DataTemplate` without an `x:Key` will be automatically applied to all objects of the type specified by the `DataType` property.

You can read more about data templating on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.110).aspx

**Edit:**

Add a `SelectedConnection` property to your main window view model class:

```
private Connection _connection;
public Connection SelectedConnection
{
    get
    {
        return _connection;
    }
    set
    {
        _connection = value;
        OnProprtyChanged();
    }
}
```

...and bind the `SelectedItem` property of the `ListBox` to this one:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbVerbindungen" .... ItemsSource="{Binding Connections}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedConnection}" DisplayMemberPath="ConnectionName">
...
```

Then you should be able to bind the `Content` property of the `ContentControl` to the UI property like this:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="ERP">
        <ContentControl Name="ccERP" Background="#FFE5E5E5" 
                                Content="{Binding DataContext.SelectedConnection.ERP.PluginInstance.UI, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"/>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: Well, the plugin needs to have the view then, since the plugin determines "how it looks like", right? So I'd need to have a UserControl called PluginUserControl in each plugin? EDIT: There's not gonna be one view for all plugins but rather each plugin needs to bring it's own view

Comment: You could create a UserControl and a DataTemplate for each concrete type of a Plugin. So the class PluginA is represented by a PluginAUserControl and PluginB is represented by a PluginBUserControl and so on.

Comment: Well, problem is: I aim for the goal, that each plugin can bring it's own UI. Wouldn't I have to create the PluginAUserControl inside the host project then? That's limit the amount of plugins then

Comment: You could create the UserControl and the DataTemplate in a ResourceDictionary that you merge into your App.xaml programmatically: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030580/dynamically-loading-resource-dictionary-files-to-a-wpf-application-gives-an-erro

Comment: Sounds good, however how'd I build the URI? Can you build an URI to point inside an assembly? The plugins are .dll files, so I'd need get the path to them

Comment: You could use a pack Uri: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx. It requires you to add a reference to the assembly though.

Comment: Not possible since the plugins will be loaded dynamically... Seems like there's no easy way to do this, huh?

Comment: I am afraid you're actual question becomes unclearer for each comment you make. It seems like you should break it down a bit.

Comment: I want my host application to load plugins from assemblies. Those plugins must implement IPlugin and (should be) require a UI in some form. Using the UI as a property works, when I do `contentControlErp.Content = ERPPlugins[0].PluginInstance.UI;` but doesn't when I try it with a binding. I don't like to write the code like that, since I'd need to handle the lbVerbindungen SelectionChanged event and is generally unwanted, so I rather want a solution (it doesn't have to be a UserControl or ContentControl) which works with those very dynamic bindings. I hope it's more clear now

Comment: Bind the Content property of the ContentControl to the UI property that returns the UserControl?

Comment: I edited my question. That's what I'm trying to do already (It's in the MainWindow.xaml) but that isn't working for some reason

Comment: Still doesn't display anything for me. The idea with SelectedConnection came to me as well, since I need it for a different spot too. Weirdly enough, if I bind the Content to `SelectedConnection.ERP.PluginInstance.Info.Name`, it shows the name. So there's nothing wrong with the binding I guess..

Comment: Then you need to make sure that the UI property returns what you would expect.

Comment: Hmm... It works when using code, but not when using Bindings... Do you know, if data contexts instantiate classes different than in code?

Comment: What does "when using code" acually means? Do you just set the Content property or do you create a binding?

Comment: Before I switched my code to MVVM (since I didn't know anything about it 2 days ago), I've had listened to the SelectionChanged event in the listbox and set the ContentControl Content property in that listener. Now, using MVVM, the equivalen (which you posted) doesn't work for some reason

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Your issue is not reproducible based on the (lack of) information you have provided.