# cannot load xaml in resourcedictionary

Tags: c#

I'm trying to load a xaml file inside a ResourceDictionary what I did is create a Dictionary like this:

```
ResourceDictionary dict = new ResourceDictionary();
```

and then:

```
dict.Source = new Uri(""pack://application:,,,/jusapp;component/Resources/Languages/it.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
```

now I've the following application folders structure:

```
AppName
    Resources
         Languages
               en.xaml 
               it.xaml
```

unfortunately I get this error:

> cannot find the resource

but the resource exist, why happen this?

Comment: did you add your resource as as embedded resource?

Comment: yes in app xaml

Comment: I mean what is the build action for it.xaml if you look at the properties

Comment: yes in the property I've also set as embedded resource

Comment: Can you try it by giving it an absolute location?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically loading resource dictionary files to a wpf application gives an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030580/dynamically-loading-resource-dictionary-files-to-a-wpf-application-gives-an-erro)

Answer (score 0):

If you are building localized application with satellite assemblies please make sure to have following annotation in AssemblyInfo.cs

```
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-US", UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.Satellite)]
```